# wsgi directory in gunicorn service file not recognised

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

[image]

I want some help to fix this issue. myproject.wsgi in gunicorn is not recognised.
I created a user `flolog` with sudo privileges. My project structure is as follows (the first directory i created is `flo-log` and it contains other directories in d django app):

```
:~/
    flo-log/
        account/
        logistics/
            settings.py
            wsgi.py
            ...
        manage.py
        ...
    flologenv/
    requirements.txt
```

Content of gunicorn file is:

[image]

How do I fix it? Or is there any resources that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is difficult to define the problem without your project structure, but seems to me in the working directory you give the path to app folder, but not to root folder. Here are my settings which could help you to configure your wsgi. "conf" is the name of app with settings and asgi wsgi files.

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.sock

[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon for Django Project
Before=nginx.service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/www/app/root_folder
ExecStart=/home/www/app/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --log-level debug --bind unix:/home/www/app/root_folder/conf.sock conf.wsgi:application
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=gunicorn
User=root
Group=www-data


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aptem. I'm yet to get a workable solution, I have tried to update my code based on your comment but the major issue persists. I have updated my question to include my project structure.

Comment: Try to change your working directory to "/home/flolog/flo-log"